# About the IO-APIC 82093AA

Tags: x86, apic

I want to program the IO-APIC & Local-APIC in my loader code, the code runs after BIOS.

I've read the i82093AA datasheet, and found that the register base is defined by PIIX3's APICBASE register. How can I read the "PIIX3 APICBASE" register?

As I know IO-APIC register base is 0xFEC00000 by default, but the BIOS may change it. So I want to find a way to get the base correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with a built-in APIC, everything is actually very simple. All you need to do is to read a model-specific register which contains the `APICBASE`. Here is a basic list of [MSRs](http://www.cs.inf.ethz.ch/stricker/lab/doc/intel-part4.pdf).

To read a MSR, use the `rdmsr` instruction (privileged).

```
mov ecx, 0x1B ; ECX=register address
xor eax, eax  ; value of unimplemented bits in MSR will turn undefined when moved to
xor edx, edx  ; EDX:EAX, so I set everything to 0
rdmsr 
; EDX:EAX now contains APICBASE
```

When speaking about the PIIX3 external APIC, from PIIX3 documentation:

> ### APICBASE—APIC BASE ADDRESS RELOCATION REGISTER (Function 0)
>
> **Address Offset:** 80h
>   **Default Value:** 00h 
>   **Attribute:** Read/Write
>
> This register provides the modifier for the APIC base address. APIC is
>   mapped in the memory space at the locations `0xFEC0xy00` and `0xFEC0xy10`
>   (`x=0-F`, `y=0/4/8/C`). The value of `y` is defined by bits [1,0] and
>   the value of `x` is defined by bits [5:2]. Thus, the relocation
>   register provides 1-Kbyte address granularity (i.e., potentially up to
>   64 IOAPICs can be uniformly addresses in the memory space). The
>   default value of 00h provides mapping of the IOAPIC unit at the
>   addresses `0xFEC00000` and `0xFEC00010`.

[A look](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pci/ioapic.c?v=2.6.35) on a driver actually interfacing PCI for this kind of data may be helpful.

Many of sources I've come through on internet used fixed `0xFEC00000` and didn't care about possibility of it being different. But as PIIX3 documentation says, `0xFEC00000` is guaranteed default value and you don't have to think about it further.

Comment: why not to use local APIC?  I think IO- and Local- APICs both need to be programmed.

Comment: I am using built-in APIC. I've read the Intel64 & IA-32 software developer's manual chapter 10, vol 3A. Most of the text talk about Local APIC, I can't find anything to show how to config the IO-APIC! Also, I can't find any IO-APIC related registers in the chapter.

Comment: I think for a built-in APIC, the IO-APIC should be also built-in logically. Right? Is the IO-APIC in built-in APIC exact the same as i82093AA?

Comment: From wikipedia: *There are two components in the Intel APIC system, the local APIC (LAPIC) and the I/O APIC. There is one LAPIC in each CPU in the system. In the very first implementation, the LAPIC was a discrete circuit, the 82489DX, but thereafter it was integrated in Intel processors. There is typically one I/O APIC for each peripheral bus in the system.* You program one or another.